# Creating lists from rows with different lengths in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list for each column in python of my data that looks like this:

```
399.75833     561.572000000        399.75833     561.572000000  a_Fe I 399.73920 nm
399.78316     523.227000000        399.78316     523.227000000  
399.80799     455.923000000        399.80799     455.923000000  a_Fe I 401.45340 nm
399.83282     389.436000000        399.83282     389.436000000  
399.85765     289.804000000        399.85765     289.804000000
```

The problem is that each row of my data is a different length. Is there anyway to format the remaining spaces of the shorter rows with a space so they are all the same length?

I would like my data to be in the form:

```
list one= [399.75833, 399.78316, 399.80799, 399.83282, 399.85765]
list two= [561.572000000, 523.227000000, 455.923000000, 389.436000000, 289.804000000]
list three= [a_Fe, " ", a_Fe, " ", " "]
```

This is the code I used to import the data into python:

```
fh  = open('help.bsp').read()
the_list = []
for line in fh.split('\n'):
    print line.strip()
    splits = line.split()
    if  len(splits) ==1 and splits[0]== line.strip():
        splits = line.strip().split(',')
    if splits:the_list.append(splits)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `izip_longest` to make your column lists, since standard `zip` will only run till the shortest length in the given list of arrays.

```
from itertools import izip_longest
with open('workfile', 'r') as f:
    fh = f.readlines()

# Process all the rows line by line
rows = [line.strip().split() for line in fh]
# Use izip_longest to get all columns, with None's filled in blank spots
cols = [col for col in izip_longest(*rows)]
# Then run your type conversions for your final data lists
list_one = [float(i) for i in cols[2]]
list_two = [float(i) for i in cols[3]]
# Since you want " " instead of None for blanks
list_three = [i if i else " " for i in cols[4]]
```

Output:

```
>>> print list_one
[399.75833, 399.78316, 399.80799, 399.83282, 399.85765]
>>> print list_two
[561.572, 523.227, 455.923, 389.436, 289.804]
>>> print list_three
['a_Fe', ' ', 'a_Fe', ' ', ' ']
```

Answer (score 0):

So, your lines are either whitespace delimited or comma delimited, and if comma delimited, the line contains no whitespace?  (note that if `len(splits)==1` is true, then `splits[0]==line.strip()` is also true).  That's not the data you're showing, and not what you're describing.

To get the lists you want from the data you show:

```
with open('help.bsp') as h:
    the_list = [ line.strip().split() for line in h.readlines() ]
list_one = [ d[0] for d in the_list ]
list_two = [ d[1] for d in the_list ]
list_three = [ d[4] if len(d) > 4 else ' ' for d in the_list ]
```

If you're reading comma separated (or similarly delimited) files, I always recommend using the `csv` module - it handles a lot of edge cases that you may not have considered.